# Option Strict error with method signatures

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, methods, method-signature

Option Strict throws some errores in these signatures:

```
Private Sub NotifyIcon_Systray_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) _
Handles RadMenuItem_Hide.Click,
        RadMenuItem_Show.Click,
        NotifyIcon_Systray.MouseDoubleClick

End Sub

Private Sub RadListControl_ProcessList_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) _
Handles RadListControl_ProcessList.DoubleClick

End Sub
```

The original signatures are: `sender As Object, e as EventArgs` but I changed them to `MouseEventArgs` because I need to determine the button pressed with the peoperty `e.Button`.

How can fix this problem?

Comment: Too early in the morning? A `MouseEventArgs` can be casted to `EventArgs` because it's derived from `EventArgs`.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå thankyou so much that is an easier solution just using a DirectCat(e, MouseeventArgs)

Comment: Yup. That, `TryCast` or `TypeOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is quite strange but you can do the following:

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
    Private Event NewClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RaiseEvent NewClick(sender, CType(e, MouseEventArgs))
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewClickHandler(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.NewClick
        MsgBox(e.X & "x" & e.Y & vbCrLf & e.Button.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You basically handle the correct signature, cast `e` to `MouseEventArgs` and then reraise a custom event that has a signature with `MouseEventArgs`.

Edit:
I have dug around a bit in the `System.Windows.Forms.Control` class and the reason that this works is, that the control's `OnClick` event is actually raised with a `MouseEventArgs` and not a simple `EventArgs`. It's just then cast to `EventArgs` (which obviously works since `MouseEventArgs` inherits from `EventArgs`).

From the `Control` code:

```
If flag AndAlso Not AddressOf Me.ValidationCancelled Then
    If Not Me.GetState(67108864) Then
        Me.OnClick(New MouseEventArgs(button, clicks, NativeMethods.Util.SignedLOWORD(AddressOf m.LParam), NativeMethods.Util.SignedHIWORD(AddressOf m.LParam), 0))
        Me.OnMouseClick(New MouseEventArgs(button, clicks, NativeMethods.Util.SignedLOWORD(AddressOf m.LParam), NativeMethods.Util.SignedHIWORD(AddressOf m.LParam), 0))
    Else
        '...
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't arbitrarily change the type of that second parameter.  The `Click` event passes an `EventArgs` object to its handlers.  Your changing the type of the parameter won't magically change the type of that object.  You can only use a parameter of type `MouseEventArgs` if the signature of the event matches that.  It does for `MouseClick` and `MouseDoubleClick` but it does not for `Click` or `DoubleClick`.  You can't change that.

Comment: `You can't change that.` I changed it as you seen, and it works perfectlly, I can receive an `e` object of type `MouseEventargs` with the `e.Button` property working properly for both `Click` and `DoubleClick` events.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - It works perfectly?  I thought you said you were getting Option Strict errors?

Comment: But If I disable Option Strict I can compile and it works... because like people said above MouseEventargs derives from Eventargs, thanks for your help